# SDL_Window Being Resized Unwantedly

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I am working on a small program for school. It includes a 3D crime scene (I use OpenGL to display it), some instructions, and a main menu. However, I am faced with quite an unwanted problem.

 
The problem I have encountered is as follows: when I run the program, it has the desired window size (Screen width * 0.85); however, when the program enters the main loop, it shrinks.

What is strange, is that the aspect ratio seemingly does not change, merely the window size.

Here is my main loop:

```
 while (!quit) {
        if (mainMenu) {
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(mainWindow);
            SDL::keyTesting();

            menuImage->drawImage(mainSurface);

            instructionButton->drawButton(mainSurface);
            crimeButton->drawButton(mainSurface);

            SDL_Delay(10);
        } 
        else if (instructions) {
            SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(mainWindow);
            SDL::keyTesting();

            instructionsImage->drawImage(mainSurface);

            backButton->drawButton(mainSurface);

            SDL_Delay(10);
        }
        else if(modelView) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                SDL::keyTesting();

            GLfloat currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
            deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
            lastFrame = currentFrame;

            glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(modelProgram);

            glUniform3f(viewPosLoc, camera.Position.x, camera.Position.y, camera.Position.z);

            glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(camera.Zoom, (float)windowWidth/(float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 250.0f);
            glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
            glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

            glm::mat4 modelMat;
            modelMat = glm::translate(modelMat, glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.75f, 0.0f));
            modelMat = glm::scale(modelMat, glm::vec3(1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(modelMat));

            model->Draw(modelProgram);

            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(mainWindow);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you are mixing SDL rendering with OpenGL. As a general rule this is bad and OpenGL doesn't play nicely with other rendering. If you are using OpenGL just use it for everything. It's possible (but not definite) that this is interfering with the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN flag.